# Adding durations in HMS

Tags: r, lubridate

My apologies if it is a repeat question. I'm not experienced working with timestamp data in R.

I have a dataset that contains a duration data in HMS format. I want to find the total sum of these values.

```
library(lubridate)
name <- c("one", "one", "two", "two") 
duration <- lubridate::hms("38H 3M 24S", "6H 50M 58S", "31M 54S", "8H 13M 51S") 
data <- data.frame(name , duration, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

If I add elements directly I get something that does not account for the carrying over of time on the 60.

```r
d1 <- data$duration[1] + data$duration[2]
d1
```

This returns "44H 53M 82S" - 82 seconds should be 1M 22S

Similar issues with the sum function

```r
d2 <- sum(data$duration)
d2
```

this returns 82.

I'm looking down the path of converting hms to seconds, summing those values and converting back to HMS and I thought surely someone has had to add HMS together before?

My end goal is to be able to do something like this

```r
d4 <- data %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   summarise(totalTime = sum(duration))
```

The result being a dataframe with

name    | duration

one     | "45h 22m 22s"

two     | " 8h 45m 45s"

Thanks in advance for the comments.

Comment: Please show the expected output.  Perhaps `data %>% mutate(duration = period_to_seconds(duration)) %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(totalTime = sum(duration, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: @akrun Thanks this a useful. Having the summary in seconds allowed me to bring this back to period. 
`data %>% mutate(duration = period_to_seconds(duration)) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(totalTime = sum(duration, na.rm = TRUE))%>%
  mutate(dur2 = hseconds_to_period(totalTime)) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there is some weirdness happening here, but I've got something that will work for me.

Working off of novica suggestion

I implemented this

```r
d4 <- data %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(totalTime = as.period(seconds(sum(as.numeric(duration1))), unit = "hours"))
```

Here is the odd part. 
This returns the expected value on the first group and an incorrect value on the second group.

name  |  totalTime

one   |  44H 54M 22S

two   |  45S

I tried troubleshooting this with no luck, so I moved on and ended up with this not so elegant solution that works.

```r
d4 <- data %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(duration2 = as.numeric(duration1)) %>%  # as.numeric converts hms to seconds
  dplyr::summarise(timeInHours = sum(duration2)*0.0002777777784,
                   hours = floor(`timeInHours`),
                   minutes1 = (timeInHours - hours)*60, 
                   minutes = floor(minutes1),
                   seconds = round((minutes1-minutes) *60, digits = 0),
                   duration = paste0(hours, "H ", minutes, "M ", seconds, "S"),
                   hms = hms(duration))
```

After you select the columns your interested in you can end up with 
name  |  duration

one   |  44H 54M 22S

two   |  8H 45M 45S

Basically, this just applies the math to convert seconds to hours then convert the remainder to minutes and that reminder to second. Which feel like a roundabout way to add HMS values

I don't like this solution, but I'd like to keep with the dplyr structure, so I'm going to roll with it for now.

If I come up with something new I'll pass it along.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
d1 <- as.period(seconds(data$duration[1]) + seconds(data$duration[2]), unit = "hours")
d1
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Your recommidation did not quite working in the group_by then summarise structure. I don't know why. But I provide an example in my response to this question